# Java Sockets: bind() and connect() method issue

Tags: java, sockets

Upon executing below program, why do `bind()` and `connect()` methods immediately throw an exception?

Without using `bind()` method, `connect()` method is blocking the execution for 4 seconds. What could be the reason?

```java
package test1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Test73 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long beginTime = 0;
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            System.out.println(socket.getPort());
            System.out.println(socket.getLocalPort());
            // socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 7777));
            System.out.println(socket.getPort());
            System.out.println(socket.getLocalPort());
            beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("1.1.1.1", 8888), 4000);
            System.out.println(socket.getPort());
            System.out.println(socket.getLocalPort());
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("client end!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(endTime - beginTime);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

bottom code is native source code,it is openJDK source.This problem I feel with the underlying C + + implementation, so the bottom source code is posted!

```
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_java_net_DualStackPlainSocketImpl_waitForConnect
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jint fd, jint timeout) {
    int rv, retry;
    int optlen = sizeof(rv);
    fd_set wr, ex;
    struct timeval t;

    FD_ZERO(&wr);
    FD_ZERO(&ex);
    FD_SET(fd, &wr);
    FD_SET(fd, &ex);
    t.tv_sec = timeout / 1000;
    t.tv_usec = (timeout % 1000) * 1000;

    /*
     * Wait for timeout, connection established or
     * connection failed.
     */
    rv = select(fd+1, 0, &wr, &ex, &t);

    /*
     * Timeout before connection is established/failed so
     * we throw exception and shutdown input/output to prevent
     * socket from being used.
     * The socket should be closed immediately by the caller.
     */
    if (rv == 0) {
        JNU_ThrowByName(env, JNU_JAVANETPKG "SocketTimeoutException",
                        "connect timed out");
        shutdown( fd, SD_BOTH );
        return;
    }

    /*
     * Socket is writable or error occurred. On some Windows editions
     * the socket will appear writable when the connect fails so we
     * check for error rather than writable.
     */
    if (!FD_ISSET(fd, &ex)) {
        return;         /* connection established */
    }

    /*
     * Connection failed. The logic here is designed to work around
     * bug on Windows NT whereby using getsockopt to obtain the
     * last error (SO_ERROR) indicates there is no error. The workaround
     * on NT is to allow winsock to be scheduled and this is done by
     * yielding and retrying. As yielding is problematic in heavy
     * load conditions we attempt up to 3 times to get the error reason.
     */
    for (retry=0; retry<3; retry++) {
        NET_GetSockOpt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR,
                       (char*)&rv, &optlen);
        if (rv) {
            break;
        }
        Sleep(0);
    }

    if (rv == 0) {
        JNU_ThrowByName(env, JNU_JAVANETPKG "SocketException",
                        "Unable to establish connection");
    } else {
        NET_ThrowNew(env, rv, "connect");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind to 127.0.0.1 you can only connect to local addresses in the same host, and therefore you can't connect to 1.1.1.1. If you don't bind, `connect()` will choose an appropriate local address to bind to that can route to the target address.

`connect()` is not an instaneous operation: it requires a three-way packet exchange. In this case you failed to connect to 1.1.1.1 as well, so you got the 4000ms connect timeout you specified.

Comment: EJP~welcome you ~~but  i question is   connect method timeout parameter,,why  blocking 4s? why no blcking 4s??

Comment: Can be tested on the computer, my problem is not connected to the server. If you do not execute the bind () method will connect () method block 4 seconds, if the execution of BIND () will immediately appear abnormal, I have native source looked at a look, do not understand, come to consult.

Comment: I've answered your question. If you don't understand my answer the way it is already written, I cannot help you further.

Comment: Then why does the bind () method occur immediately after the exception,
is not a routing address.
If there is no binding, you need routing addressing?
The strangest thing is that the exception appears, one is SocketException, the other is socketimeoutexception. Exception information is not the same as the logic of the underlying walk.

Comment: EJP,,i update code :socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.101", 7777));
I understand what you mean, the code can run, thank you very much!

Comment: If you can't connect because the bind-address is wrong, you get the failure immediately. What is there to wait for? There is nothing strange about the two exceptions being different. Unclear what you're asking.